# Github Actions How to list docker images you created in one step and use that output in another step

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I have a step in my workflow which builds multiple docker images. I need to add another step which is going to list **only** the docker images created in the previous step. (as there will be some other images in my environment I don't need to list).

This is my starting point but I don't know how to proceed.

```
- name: List Docker Images
        id: docker_outputs
        run: |
          DOCKER_IMAGES=???
          run: echo "::set-output name=docker_images::${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGES }}"
```

Previously, I defined the output

```
outputs:
      docker_images: ${{ steps.docker_outputs.outputs.docker_images}}
```

Comment: How does the previous step look like? How are you building those images?